# Can I track change history or 'Time in State' for Sharepoint List Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, issue-tracking

Can an Item's change history be recorded in SharePoint?

I have a list that is essentially an issue tracking list. Leadership wants to know the amount of time items are in certain statuses in the workflow. They want data to see which status's are taking the longest time.

Sorry if this is a novice question. I'm new to SharePoint and this is my first SharePoint list. We use SharePoint Online.

Thank you for your help.

zach

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use MS flow to log the time when the status change. If you want to have clear time logging, it may be better to create a new logging list to record such process.

Say, in the other list, you create columns corresponding to your status, and use the flow triggered when an item is created/modified in your original list. Use the flow to check if you have created new item with the same title in the logging list. If no, create a new one and update the time of current status, if yes, then just check the current status, recording the time to corresponding column. Then you can view the time of each status in the logging list.

I built a simple sample and works in my end, the test list has status ABC
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable Versioning for the list.  List Settings -> Versioning Settings

But it might be better for your example to create another list as a log of changes and have the workflow update it on each change.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I think that's what I'll do. Since a status can change back and forth, I'd like to have one variable calculating 'days in state', and each time the state changes, populate a different multivalued field with the (Item - State - Days in state)